# Regex matching from dictionary in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe that contains data below for column 'product_location'. Just showing single row value as reference

```
df.product_location[0]=[{'product':'christmas-socks-2019','store':'Downtown-A,Montgomery'}, {'product':'easter-socks-2018','store':'Euston'},{'product':'easter-socks-2019','source':'Euston'}]
df.product_location[1]=[{'product':'christmas-mugs-2019','store':'Montgomery'}, {'product':'easter-mugs-2018','store':'Euston, Downtown-B'},{'product':'easter-mugs-2019','source':'High-Street'}]
df.product_location[2]=[{'product':'christmas-card-2019','store':'Downtown-A, Montgomery'}, {'product':'easter-card-2018','store':'Euston'},{'product':'easter-card-2019','source':'Euston'}]
df.product_location[3]=[{'product':'christmas-chocolate-2019','store':'Downtown-A'}, {'product':'easter-chocolate-2018','store':'Euston'},{'product':'easter-chocolate-2017','source':'Euston'}]
```

I am trying to regex extract the year (eg.2019,2018) from the product names and count the # of stores for each product and produce the year with the highest # of count.

So for example for row [0] i would expect the output to be 2019 as it has the highest store count ('Downtown-A, Montgomery, Euston')

Expected output (blank if no single year has highest count)

```
[0] '2019'
[1] (blank)
[2] '2019'
[3] (blank)
```

what would be the best way to do this for all rows in the dataframe?

Comment: are you able to add a few rows from your data frame with your intended output from those rows?

Comment: sure added some more rows

Comment: so ur data is a collection of dictionaries?

Comment: yes thats correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering a row to be the list `db`

```py
from collections import Counter

db=[{'product':'christmas-socks-2019','store':'Downtown-A,Montgomery'}, {'product':'easter-socks-2018','store':'Euston'},{'product':'easter-socks-2019','source':'Euston'}]
```

Extracting the years alone from list of dictionaries :

```py
products = [int(d['product'].split('-')[-1]) for d in db]
counter = list(Counter(products).items())
```

Using your condition

```py
if counter[0][1] == 1:
    print('blank')
else:
    print(counter[0][0])
```

For traversing through the dataframe and implementing the logic for each row, you could try out this:

```py
for i in range(len(df)):
    db = df.loc[i, 'product_location']
    products = [int(d['product'].split('-')[-1]) for d in db]
    counter = list(Counter(products).items())

    if counter[0][1] == 1:
        print('blank')
    else:
        print(counter[0][0])
```

Comment: awesome! and what would be the easiest way to apply to all rows in the column 'product location'?

Comment: Probably have to traverse the dataframe and use `loc` or `iloc` to get each row, I couldn't try that as you have not included the dataframe structure. Happy this helped you :)

Comment: I have written  a block of code for it anyway, do try it.

Comment: awesome! what if instead i would want to skip any products that contain '2019' in the name? How would i be able to say regex match those values and remove them from the count?

Comment: No idea as it's been almost 2 weeks man. Can you update your question with the new desired output your mentioning. you can appreciate me with an upvote to my answer if it helped you.